# How to check if device orientation is landscape left vs right in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm aware of the ability to detect landscape vs portrait, but I'd like to vary how I'm using the safe area on devices with notch features (iPhone X) based on if the notch is on the left when in landscape left or on the right when in landscape right. In swift you can do this: UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flutter don't give us left or right yet but [this](https://pub.dev/packages/native_device_orientation) library can help you.